# How to convert a list of objects to two level dictionary?

Tags: c#, collections, dictionary, extension-methods

I have a list of customer objects (e.x:  List customers)

```
 public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public bool DidLive { get; set; }
    }
```

What I need to do is to convert this "customers" collection into a `dictionary` like follows,

**"Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, bool>>**" 
Where the outer key is the "ID" and the inner key is the "City".

Can this be done using `"GroupBy"` or `"ToDictionary"` extension methods of `"IEnumerable<T>"`?

Comment: What is the use of inner dictionary `Dictionary<string, bool>` when it will have only one item.

Comment: In a word: Yes. Group your groups, and make a dictionary from the inside out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you have multiple Customer objects with the same Id but with different Cities (if this isn't the case and  the inner dictionary will always contain one item, go with @oleksii's answer).

```
var result = customers.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
                      .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                                    group => group.ToDictionary(c => c.City, 
                                                                c => c.DidLive));
```

Of course, this will throw an exception if there multiple customers with identical Ids *and* Cities.

Comment: Thank you, your method works. Actually I have "different customers who has lived(or not) in different cities". What I want to get is a dictionary which give me the customer id's along with their city names, whether they have lived or not.

Answer (score 1):

That's a place to start

```
var data = new List<Customer>();

data.ToDictionary(item => item.ID, 
                    item => new Dictionary<string, bool>
                    {
                        {item.City,item.DidLive}
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I have "different customers who has lived(or not) in different cities". What I want to get is a dictionary which give me the customer id's along with their city names, whether they have lived or not. So in this scenario, your method breaks by giving an ArguementException stating that "An item with the same key has already been added." But "Ani"s method works. Thank you for your time!